# Content not loading when pressing button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a long list that only shows the first few items. I want to load more content by clicking on a button. 
I've found what I'm looking for, however, it doesn't work with li items for some weird reason.

I know this method is not efficient and that this could be done with ajax and possibly php. However, my client does not want me to use ajax and php. He's planning to keep the site I'm creating completely offline/local.

Here's what I'm working with: [CodePen](http://%3Cp%20class=%22codepen%22%20data-height=%22265%22%20data-theme-id=%220%22%20data-default-tab=%22html,result%22%20data-user=%22elmahdim%22%20data-slug-hash=%22sGkvH%22%20style=%22height:%20265px;%20box-sizing:%20border-box;%20display:%20flex;%20align-items:%20center;%20justify-content:%20center;%20border:%202px%20solid;%20margin:%201em%200;%20padding:%201em;%22%20data-pen-title=%22Load%20more%20content%20with%20jQuery%22%3E%20%20%20%3Cspan%3ESee%20the%20Pen%20%3Ca%20href=%22https://codepen.io/elmahdim/pen/sGkvH/%22%3E%20%20%20Load%20more%20content%20with%20jQuery%3C/a%3E%20by%20Mahmoud%20Elmahdi%20(%3Ca%20href=%22https://codepen.io/elmahdim%22%3E@elmahdim%3C/a%3E)%20%20%20on%20%3Ca%20href=%22https://codepen.io%22%3ECodePen%3C/a%3E.%3C/span%3E%20%3C/p%3E%20%3Cscript%20async%20src=%22https://static.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js%22%3E%3C/script%3E)

or

```js
/*
 Load more content with jQuery - May 21, 2013
 (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
*/

$(function() {
  $(".test li").slice(0, 4).show();
  $("#loadMore").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".test.li:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
    if ($(".test.li:hidden").length == 0) {
      $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 1500);
  });
});
```

```css
.test ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
}

.test li {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dic class="test">
  <ul>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>

  </ul>

  </div>


  <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
```

Edit: fixed the issue with linking the class in html to css and js.

Comment: Your selectors don't match your HTML. There's no elements with the class `.test`, or the class `.li`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this code in place of your code

```js
$(function () {
    $("li").slice(0, 4).show();
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("li:hidden").slice(0, 4).slideDown();
        if ($("li:hidden").length == 0) {
            $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
        }
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

```css
.test ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: red;
}

.test li {
  display: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dic class="test">
  <ul>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>
    <li> item?</li>

  </ul>

  </div>


  <a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide the last few elements when loading and show it on it after clicking loadmore. Use the jquery hide and show method.

```js
/*
 Load more content with jQuery - May 21, 2013
 (c) 2013 @ElmahdiMahmoud
*/   

$(function () {
    $(".test li:hidden").slice(0, 4).show(500);
    $("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
      $(".test li:hidden").slice(0, 4).show(500);
    });
});
```

```css
.test ul{width:100%; height:auto; background:red;}
.test li{
    display:none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <ul>
    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>
        <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>    <li> item?</li>
     <li> item?</li>
    
    </ul>
  
  </div>


<a href="#" id="loadMore">Load More</a>
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be mostly working. 
One thing I'm trying to understand is: I erroneously mixed my selectors ( #test in html and .test in css and js) and the example is working well on this site. 
For some reason the code is not working when I use it in my project; that is even if I change the #test to .test. I'll look into this further and I'll let you know. 
I'm also using Jquery 3.1.1 but I'll try another version.

Comment: Thank you all for your help!
Apparently I had a misspelled "Jquery" in my html files.  
That's what happens when I use my laptop.